# Dotted Border for UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, border

I need to add a dotted border style for `UIView`. I dont want to use `CGRect` and `setDash` as you cant remove it after setting it. I should be to able toggle with this border style. How do I get about it?

I have a method to add

```
-(void) addBorder
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

I get the error 'invalid context 0x0'

Comment: could you edit your question to show how you're currently adding your border?

Comment: You might get answer from here Similar post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679923/dotted-line-border-around-uiview

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40512209/1757229

Answer (score 1):

Try following method, one of my app also has same functionality & I done it using following way.

```
-(void)addDashedBorder
{
    //border definitions
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 0;
    CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
    NSInteger dashPattern1 = 4;
    NSInteger dashPattern2 = 4;
    UIColor *lineColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //drawing
    CGRect frame = view.bounds;

    CAShapeLayer *_shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    //creating a path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //drawing a border around a view
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI, -M_PI_2, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, 0);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, -M_PI_2, 0, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, M_PI_2, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI_2, M_PI, NO);

    //path is set as the _shapeLayer object's path
    _shapeLayer.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);

    _shapeLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.frame = frame;
    _shapeLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    [_shapeLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isCircle"];
    _shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.strokeColor = [lineColor CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    _shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dashPattern1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:dashPattern2], nil];
    _shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;

    //_shapeLayer is added as a sublayer of the view, the border is visible
    [view.layer addSublayer:_shapeLayer];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h` framework in project and import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in `.m` file.

And then
try following code:

```
[view.layer setBorderWidth:5.0];
[view.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DottedImage.png"]] CGColor]];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Nope, when I resize my view, the image will look bad.