# Swift: Why CAShapeLayer's Stroke and LineWidth drawn from Center

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, pie-chart, cashapelayer

I am trying for `PieChart` which having dynamic datas.

On clicking each `Pie`, it has to highlight and rest are in normal state.

Dynamically changing `lineWidth` of `CAShapeLayer`, but `lineWidth` increasing from middle path.

It has to increase from bottom to top

**Code:**

```
    let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
    let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(1.0 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(3.0 * .pi), clockwise: true)
    let progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath
    progressCircle.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    if onClick == 2 {
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 60
    } else {
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 30
    }
    
    
    progressCircle.strokeStart = strokeStart/PieChartConstant.maxPercent
    progressCircle.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.butt
    progressCircle.strokeEnd = strokeEnd/PieChartConstant.maxPercent
```

**Query:**

That increased `Pie` should in same track as like previous `Pies`. Kindly guide me, how to achieve this.

**Referred:**

[Checked_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006801/why-does-a-cashapelayers-stroke-extend-out-of-the-frame) , but couldn't achieve and also dont know how to achieve this.

**My Output:**

[image]

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: Hi @matt That increased Pie should in same track as like previous Pies. ., How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "same track". Can you show a picture of how you want them to look like?

Comment: @Sweeper Image updated., Highlighted Pie should be in same path like "REQUIRED" image

Comment: All the line widths are the same in the required image, it seems. Why are you conditionally setting `lineWidth` to different values in the first place? You should set all the line widths to the same number.

Comment: @Sweeper pls check update

Comment: Don’t try to paint shapes with mere lines (strokes) and line widths. If the goal is a pie shape draw a pie shape and fill it. The approach here is too simplistic so of course it doesn’t work.

Comment: I am asking., Why Strokes are increasing its width from centre? and Is there anyway to start increase width from bottom to top ?? @matt

Comment: Strokes increase width from the center because that’s how they work. As I said, relying on stroke to make your whole shape is just silly. Learn to draw a true circle sector. What you are doing is no way to achieve the goal drawing you’ve shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to achieve the result.,

OnClicking, need to increase this `radius`. Then, exact result achieved.

**Code:**

```
    .........
    .....
    let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
    var circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83

    if onClick == 2 { //THIS BLOCK IS USED TO INCREASE PARTICULAR PIE
        circleRadius = circleRadius + 10
    }

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(1.0 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(3.0 * .pi), clockwise: true)
    .......
    ............
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This is still not a viable or maintainable way to approach the problem. Your drawing does not resemble the original target drawing (the one on the right in https://i.stack.imgur.com/7abRT.png), and it isn't going to. Instead of undermining the design to match your code, upgrade your code to achieve the design.

Comment: My real design couldn't post here., that was confidential. I just want to know why stroke drawn from centre and is there any way to move that Pie in same track. The design which  I mentioned earlier [u have mentioned in previous comment], to represent what is meant by "SAME TRACK". And also, I dont want to go with library. I m trying with myself. So I have asked a question here. But I dont know reason for downvote. Thanks @matt

Comment: And also this simple code will help many SO followers to achieve this type of simple Pie Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you would be a lot happier drawing the whole segment shape and filling it, instead of trying to let a mere stroke represent the shape. I had no difficulty getting this sort of thing:

[image]

Each segment here was drawn as an arc, a line, an arc, a line, then fill. That approach gives complete control over how the segments are drawn, because we are drawing the segments ourselves.

Comment: Yes @matt . I have drawn a full circle and then I was trying to adjust stroke start and end. This approach was wrong.  We have to draw exact arc and then fill or use stroke as per our need. I have searched a lot and done my requirement. Thanks for ur comments. "if the goal is a pie shape draw a pie shape and fill it" - with the help of this comment., I have done.