# How do you animate the sublayers of the layer of a UIView during a UIView animation?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uiviewanimation, cabasicanimation

In a UIView animation for a view, you can animate its *subviews* being laid out by including `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` in the options parameter of `[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`. However, I cannot find a way to animate it laying out its *sublayers* when they are not some view's backing layer; they would just jump into place to match the new bounds of the view. Since I'm working with layers and not views, it seems like I have to use Core Animation instead of UIView animation, but I don't know how (and when) to do this such that the layer animation would match up to the view animation.

**That's my basic question. Read more if you want to know the concrete thing I'm trying to accomplish.**

I've created a view with a dotted border by adding a CAShapeLayer to the view's layer (see this stackoverflow question: [Dashed line border around UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679923/dotted-line-border-around-uiview)). I adjust the path of the CAShapeLayer to match the bounds of the view in `layoutSubviews`.

This works, but there is one cosmetic issue: when the view's bounds is animated in a UIView animation (like during rotation), the dotted border jumps to the new bounds of the view instead of smoothly animating to it as the view animates its bounds. That is, the right and bottom parts of the dotted border do not respectively stay hugged to the right and bottom parts of the view as the view animates. *How can I get the dotted border from the CAShapeLayer to animate alongside the view as it animates its bounds?*

What I'm doing so far is attaching a CABasicAnimation to the CAShapeLayer:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.borderLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
    self.borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    [self.borderLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:nil];
}
```

This does cause the dotted border to animate, but it does not have the right timing function and animation duration to match the view animation. Also, sometimes, we don't want the dotted border to animate like, when the view first does layout, the border should not animate from some old path to the new correct path; it should just appear.

Answer (score 28):

You might have found the answer already, but I also faced similar problems recently, since solved it, I will post the answer.

In `- layoutSubViews` method, you can get current `UIView` animation as backing layer's `CAAnimation` with `- animationForKey:` method.
Using this, You can implement `- layoutSubviews` like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // get current animation for bounds
    CAAnimation *anim = [self.layer animationForKey:@"bounds"];

    [CATransaction begin];
    if(anim) {
        // animating, apply same duration and timing function.
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:anim.duration];
        [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:anim.timingFunction];

        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
        [self.borderLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"path"];
    }
    else {
        // not animating, we should disable implicit animations.
        [CATransaction disableActions];
    }

    self.borderLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
    self.borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: I had to use the "position" property to get the animationForKey, but besides that it worked great for me!

Comment: Thanks, but I should mention, that this does not work with animation method [UIView animateWithDuration: usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations: completion:]

Comment: @Eric You can also use `bounds.size`. A quick breakpoint and inspecting animationKeys tells me there are 3 animations ongoing `[position, bounds.size, bounds.origin]`

Comment: @rintaro, if my UIView animation code doesn't have a clear key path to refer to, like calling `layoutIfNeeded()` inside `UIView.animationWithDuration:`, do you know a solution in this scenario?

Comment: I am using `layoutIfNeeded` to animate the UIView (and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` just sets the frame) and I found that using the key path "bounds.size" got me what I needed to make the sublayer animation work.

Comment: this does not work if you are trying to animate alongside the keyboard show/hide animation... (the duration and timingFunction are different)

Comment: @KlemenZagar It does, but you must use CASpringAnimation instead of CABasicAnimation in that case.

Comment: Helped me AGAIN, five years later. Thanks @AndreiStanescu @rintaro!