# How to set Dashed border color in xamarin forms Frame in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am doing an app in Xamarin.Forms for iOS.In that i need to do a design of the image shown below.

[image]

To achieve this design I used a frame and added border color for it.But I am not able to get Dashed border as specified in the image above. I am trying to get this through custom renderer. Can anyone please help me or guide me to get the exact design in the image.

That would be a gret help for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a iOS version, you can try to convert it to xamarin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679923/dashed-line-border-around-uiview

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.I will try and let you know.

Comment: Imo the best way to do this is to just show this image. Saves you a lot of time and it looks the same on any OS.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dennis.We want the same design for iPhone and iPad.If we use image it is getting stretched in iPad.

Comment: You can use SkiaSharp to draw dots and dashes around your control.

Comment: Have you found any solution? Is there any idea of how to do this for UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the Frame Renderer and add the dash pattern

```
public class CustomFrame : FrameRenderer
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        CAShapeLayer viewBorder = new CAShapeLayer();
        viewBorder.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        viewBorder.FillColor = null;
        viewBorder.LineDashPattern = new NSNumber[] { new NSNumber(5), new NSNumber(2) };
        viewBorder.Frame = NativeView.Bounds;
        viewBorder.Path = UIBezierPath.FromRect(NativeView.Bounds).CGPath;
        Layer.AddSublayer(viewBorder);

        // If you don't want the shadow effect
        Element.HasShadow = false;
    }
}
```