# BezierPath sublayer does not wrap around the whole UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm currently trying to make a dotted border around my UIView. I referred to a previous post: [Dashed line border around UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679923/dashed-line-border-around-uiview)

The left side of the UIView gets the red dotted lines but the right side misses the edge.

[image: Left side] This is left side

[image: Right side] This is right side

Here is my code which I am executing in viewDidLoad:

```
myview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
myview.layer.cornerRadius = 4

let dottedBorder = CAShapeLayer()
dottedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
dottedBorder.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
dottedBorder.frame = myview.bounds
dottedBorder.fillColor = nil
dottedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myview.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).cgPath
        
myview.layer.addSublayer(dottedBorder)
```

Comment: Close the path?

Comment: Add this line also in viewDidLayoutSubview method : dottedBorder.frame = myview.bounds

Comment: @ElTomato What do you mean by close the path?

Comment: @RajaKishan Nope, still doesn't cover the whole view

Comment: @infiniteObj See the doc for `UIBezierpath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using autolayout, you shouldn't depend on the view size inside `viewDidLoad`, because usually it equals you storyboard device size(selected is SB editor), not the real device one.

Anyway, it may change in future. All calculations depending on `frame`/`bounds` needs to be done inside  `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Something like this:

```
private let dottedBorder = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    dottedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    dottedBorder.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
    dottedBorder.fillColor = nil
    myview.layer.addSublayer(dottedBorder)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    dottedBorder.frame = myview.bounds
    dottedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myview.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).cgPath
}
```